# how is Java's epsilon no garbage collector a useful feature for the average developer?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

I understand the uses for benchmarking between different garbage collectors and JVM developers.

Also for extremely efficient programs that don't create garbage then not having a garbage collector is useful, also for very short lived programs.

What are some other use cases for this garbage collector?

Comment: Seriously.  The JEP for Epsilon explicitly lists six example usecases.  All you need to do is Google for the document!

Comment: It might be useful in development of trading robots for high frequency trading where you do not want spend time in GC at all.

Comment: thanks Ivan that seems quite on point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goals of this collector are described in [JEP 318: Epsilon: A No-Op Garbage Collector](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318):

> - Performance testing.
> - Memory pressure testing.
> - VM interface testing.
> - Extremely short lived jobs.
> - Last-drop latency improvements.
> - Last-drop throughput improvements.

The performance testing features can be very useful since the test environment will be much more predictable without GC potentially kicking in and performing expensive stop-the-world full GC cycle.